# 16 Bit HID Gamepad report descriptor gave resolution like 8 bit descriptor in android

Tags: android, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I am using MEMS sensor for my project. I am working on 16 bit HID gamepad report descriptor which has 8 buttons and 4 axis(data coming from MEMS sensor).

Firstly, I have used 8 bit HID Gamepad report descriptor and send the data over BLE. It has been checked with windows and android HTML5 gamepad tester(http://html5gamepad.com/) and both OS gives expected data in gamepad tester. Than for better resolution I changed the report descriptor and made 2 bytes HID descriptor which is attached below. This report descriptor give expected data and resolution in windows but not getting same output in android side.

Output:

16 bit data resolution in Windows: 
0.147723, 0.148028, 0.149737, 0.150103, 0.152056, 0.154070, 0.154957, 0.156087, 0.156146

16 bit data resolution in Android: 
0.144566, 0.153294, 0.165441, 0.170080, 0.183691, 0.191595, 0.199957

Here, I attached the screenshot of html5 gamepad tester(in chrome).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai7ZP.jpg)

It shows that, i send quaternion data from sensor and it gaves 4 axis value(X, Y, Z, W) which is (0, 0, 0, 1) in initial state. so data comes between the range of -1 to 1 in gamepad tester.
In 16 bit, i use Logical minimum : -32767 to Logical maximum : 32767

so i have a doubt that is there any limitation in android side for HID report descriptor?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Sn8.jpg)

`0x05, 0x01,                   //USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
  0x09, 0x05,                   //USAGE (Game Pad)
  0xa1, 0x01,                   //COLLECTION (APPLICATION)
  0xa1, 0x00,                    //   COLLECTION (Physical)
  0x05, 0x09,                   //USAGE_PAGE (Button)
  0x19, 0x01,                   //USAGE_MINIMUM (Button1)
  0x29, 0x08,                   //USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 8)
  0x15, 0x00,                   //LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
  0x25, 0x01,                   //LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(1)
  0x95, 0x08,                   //REPORT_COUNT (8)
  0x75, 0x01,                   //REPORT_SIZE (1)
  0x81, 0x02,                   //INPUT(Data, Var, Abs)
  0x05, 0x01,                   //USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
  0x09, 0x30,                   //USAGE (X)
  0x09, 0x31,                   //USAGE (Y)
  0x09, 0x32,                   //USAGE (Z)
  0x09, 0x35,                   //USAGE (Rz)
  0x16, 0x01, 0x80                   //LOGICAL_MINIMUM(-32767)
  0x26, 0xff, 0x7f                  //LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(32767)
  0x75, 0x10,                   //REPORT_SIZE(16)
  0x95, 0x04,                   //REPORT_COUNT(4)
  0x81, 0x02,                   //INPUT(Data,Var,Abs)
  0xc0,                     //END_Collection
  0xc0                      //END_Collection`

I hope someone would be able to help with this problem.

Thanks,

Divya.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Why 16 bit HID report descriptor does not gives expected data resolution on android?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have accidentally updated the comments instead of the actual report descriptor bytes. When I decode your descriptor I get:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 01        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 05        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010005 Game Pad (Application Collection)  
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x00010005: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Game Pad, Type=Application Collection)
A1 00          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x0: Page=, Usage=, Type=) <-- Error: COLLECTION must be preceded by a USAGE <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CP (Physical Collection)
05 09            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page 
19 01            (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (Selector, On/Off Control, Momentary Control, or One Shot Control)  
29 10            (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090010 Button 16 (Selector, On/Off Control, Momentary Control, or One Shot Control)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
95 10            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x10 (16) Number of fields  
75 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (16 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 30            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (Dynamic Value)  
09 31            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (Dynamic Value)  
09 32            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010032 Z (Dynamic Value)  
09 33            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010033 Rx (Dynamic Value)  
15 81            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x81 (-127)  
25 7F            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7F (127)  
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
95 04            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x04 (4) Number of fields  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (4 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Physical 
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application 
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Button Page inputReport (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
                                                     // No REPORT ID byte
                                                     // Collection: GamePad
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton1 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton2 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton3 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton4 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090004: Button 4, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton5 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090005: Button 5, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton6 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090006: Button 6, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton7 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090007: Button 7, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton8 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090008: Button 8, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton9 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090009: Button 9, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton10 : 1;                  // Usage 0x0009000A: Button 10, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton11 : 1;                  // Usage 0x0009000B: Button 11, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton12 : 1;                  // Usage 0x0009000C: Button 12, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton13 : 1;                  // Usage 0x0009000D: Button 13, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton14 : 1;                  // Usage 0x0009000E: Button 14, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton15 : 1;                  // Usage 0x0009000F: Button 15, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton16 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090010: Button 16, Value = 0 to 1
  int8_t   GD_GamePadX;                              // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = -127 to 127
  int8_t   GD_GamePadY;                              // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = -127 to 127
  int8_t   GD_GamePadZ;                              // Usage 0x00010032: Z, Value = -127 to 127
  int8_t   GD_GamePadRx;                             // Usage 0x00010033: Rx, Value = -127 to 127
} inputReport_t;
```

Try using this instead:

```
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 01        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 05        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010005 Game Pad (Application Collection)  
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x00010005: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Game Pad, Type=Application Collection)
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010001 Pointer (Physical Collection)  
A1 00          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x00010001: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Pointer, Type=Physical Collection)
05 09            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page 
19 01            (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (Selector, On/Off Control, Momentary Control, or One Shot Control)  
29 08            (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090008 Button 8 (Selector, On/Off Control, Momentary Control, or One Shot Control)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
95 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x08 (8) Number of fields  
75 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (8 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 30            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (Dynamic Value)  
09 31            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (Dynamic Value)  
09 32            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010032 Z (Dynamic Value)  
09 33            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010033 Rx (Dynamic Value)  
16 0180          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x8001 (-32767)  
26 FF7F          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7FFF (32767)  
75 10            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x10 (16) Number of bits per field  
95 04            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x04 (4) Number of fields  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (4 fields x 16 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Physical 
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application 
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Button Page inputReport (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
                                                     // No REPORT ID byte
                                                     // Collection: GamePad Pointer
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadPointerButton1 : 1;            // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadPointerButton2 : 1;            // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadPointerButton3 : 1;            // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadPointerButton4 : 1;            // Usage 0x00090004: Button 4, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadPointerButton5 : 1;            // Usage 0x00090005: Button 5, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadPointerButton6 : 1;            // Usage 0x00090006: Button 6, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadPointerButton7 : 1;            // Usage 0x00090007: Button 7, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadPointerButton8 : 1;            // Usage 0x00090008: Button 8, Value = 0 to 1
  int16_t  GD_GamePadPointerX;                       // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = -32767 to 32767
  int16_t  GD_GamePadPointerY;                       // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = -32767 to 32767
  int16_t  GD_GamePadPointerZ;                       // Usage 0x00010032: Z, Value = -32767 to 32767
  int16_t  GD_GamePadPointerRx;                      // Usage 0x00010033: Rx, Value = -32767 to 32767
} inputReport_t;
```

Edit: I reduced the button count from 16 to 8 to match your decription of the controller

Comment: Thanks for answer but i think you won't understand my question. I know my report descriptor must be correct because it gives data in both OS(windows and android), windows gives expected resolution of 16 bit data but right now the problem looks like Android is unable to recognise the 16 bit accurate data resolution coming from my HID device because something might be missing from the Descriptor of my device. If I can make sure that the Device Descriptor and its Configuration is perfect, I can move forward. so I just want to know that is there any limitation for HID on android?

Comment: Different operating systems have varying degrees of tolerance for less-than-perfect report descriptors - often requiring driver hacks to allow widely used hardware to function correctly for particular vendor and product ids. The  report descriptor you posted is definitely specifying 8-bit data, so I don't see how Windows (or Android) could possibly parse a report with 16-bit precision. Anyway, you've got nothing to lose by trying the suggested report descriptor - give it a try and see if it helps :)

Comment: BTW, note the addition of the 09 01 local usage that identifies the physical collection as a Pointer collection...that could be significant (again depending on the operating system)

Comment: I tried your suggested report descriptor but i got same output as before. And yes this is 16 bit HID report descriptor because here i used logical minimum -32767 to logical maximum 32767 so, I got output like as i described in my question.so, there we can see the difference of the data in windows and android.

Comment: Bdw, From where you decode the report descriptor? Can you please tell me the name of the software tool of that?

Comment: ...a free open source program I wrote a few years ago: https://sourceforge.net/projects/hidrdd/